# is there a way to intercept HTTP error code in CustomTabsIntent?

Tags: android, webview

when using webview we can add a custom `WebViewClient` which have `onReceivedError()` methode to intercept the http error code but since i migrate to CustomTabsIntent i didn't find a way to intercept them.

Comment: *i didn't find a way to intercept them* ... Because you can't ... CustomTabs are not WebViews

Comment: is it documented anywhere?

Comment: What for? it's a different process ... but you can always read first link from internet search